# Nested Select in LLBLGen

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, llblgenpro

So, I have the following tables:

[image: Tables]

Using LLBLGen 2.6 (Adapter Version - No Linq), SQL Server, and .NET 3.5, how would I write the following query?

```
SELECT o.ObjectID 
FROM Object o 
INNER JOIN ObjectDetail d ON i.ObjectID = d.ObjectID 
WHERE d.CreatedDate = ( SELECT MAX(CreatedDate) 
                        FROM ObjectDetail
                        WHERE ObjectID = o.ObjectID
                      )
```

There will be more filtering, however it's not relevant to this, like if I had an **ObjectDetailType** and I wanted the max **ObjectDetail** row for a certain type.

Also, it doesn't have to select **o.ObjectID**, any / all columns will be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it

```
PredicateExpression.AddWithAnd(
  new FieldCompareSetPredicate(
    ObjectDetailFields.CreatedDate,
    null,
    ObjectDetailFields.CreatedDate.SetAggregateFunction(AggregateFunction.Max),
    null,
    SetOperator.Equal,
    (ObjectFields.ObjectID == ObjectDetailsFields.ObjectID)
 )
);
```